# Chrome devtools, remember expanded element and selection on refresh

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

It is very difficult to program when you are trying to inspect an element, say:

[image]

**Then you refresh**  the page, and chrome throws you back to:

[image]

Forcing you to open the path all over again.

Not very nice or productive use of my energy.

**Now**, I have mentioned this in the past and even filed a bug report and I remember it being taken care of at one point, but it seems to be back now. I can not find the old info to link to.

All chrome has to do is reselect the previous selected element after a delay ( which I assume must be defined statically in order to guarantee that at that time the element do exist again).

Ideally, chrome dev tools would allow us to programmatically allow us to select any **NODE** to do this selection programmatically, but i don't think we will get there.

This is very frustrating to deal with.

**Any tips?** Is this possible in other browsers? **Firefox, firebug, safari?**

Comment: The only thing you can do is to report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Related: 

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=93638

AND THIS 

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=635981&q=inspector%20preserve&can=1

Comment: This is my old one: 

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=570345&q=inspector%20element%20remember&can=1

5 years in the making.

Comment: Note that Firebug is discontinued since 2017. I guess you mean the Firefox DevTools. Have you tried it there yourself or in the Safari DevTools? Reselecting the element after a page refresh is non-trivial due to DOM changes after the page load or changes within the initial HTML structure. I guess there's no good answer to this here on Stack Overflow as it's a bug in the DevTools and you should rather provide a test case in the Chromium bug you've filed to push this forward.

Comment: @SebastianZartner yes, i've tried, I even downgraded to old enough firefox to use firebug, and I do believe it is kind of trivial. Just remember last selected element, and retry selecting it every 500 milliseconds (  or allow us to specify a clear timeout in settings ) and timeout completely after 10 seconds in case there is no longer anything to be found. There is no other approach other than polling but this could be an option a developer can choose to opt in to if dev tools is open.

Comment: @SebastianZartner Unfotunately firefox developer tools is not very good either. Buggy. Script debugging at least is not always working.

Comment: @mmm Script debugging isn't the topic of your question. In order to "Just remember last selected element" you need to define how to do that. DevTools already implement some heuristics to do that. I agree that this doesn't always work perfectly, though that's something the DevTools developers have to improve and there is no workaround for that.

Comment: Script debugging is the culprit to why firefox developer is useless. You either use a tool that can replace your entire needs or you don't. I simply mentioned why that is not a tool that can not be considered even an option. Not that it works for this case either. Define what? Last selected in console -> elements / dom, per host, or location.href.